# regex match limited list of words of max length

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match a list of 1-5 words separated by whitespace.
Each word can include either alphanumeric and "." characters and the word should have a max length of 32.

I am using the following pattern

```
^(\b[\w\.]{1,32}\b\s?){1,5}$
```

I see the following string matches even though its length is 35

```
111111111111111111...11111111111111
```

When I remove the quantifier as below then it does not match, as expected

```
^\b[\w\.]{1,32}\b\s?$
```

Why is 111111111111111111...11111111111111 matching and how do I fix the pattern so that it doesn't?

Comment: If you include a dot the regex no longer matches "words". Word boundary is not working as you expect in these scenarios. The `\b` matches in between `.1`

Answer (score 0):

There are two things in your expression that I can see are tripping you up. The first is the word boundaries, which weren't behaving as you expected. The second was the fact that you were making the whitespace optional. That's why it matched 35 characters, because it would match 32, and start matching the the next set.

I think this should match what you need: `^([\w\.]{1,32})((\s[\w\.]{1,32}){1,4})?$`.

The first group matches the first word with 1-32 characters, as you'd expect. The second group is very similar, but notice the required whitespace at the beginning. This makes it required that whitespace separates each new word and doesn't require it at the end. The whole second group is optional, so it'll match 1-5 of these words. It adds a bit of repetition and there may be ways to make it shorter, but it does the trick!

Hope that helps.